# after pc Crash,vs code doesnt get dart code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

i was working in visual code normally , using flutter and everything working normal , my pc crash and after the restart vs code show dart code in white , and click in dart in the buttom right it shows me a list where i pick the device to run the code while now it doesnt, thanks for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLwxC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkc4D.png)

flutter doctor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPt2V.png)

i created new project , still the same .

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an images

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Flutter extension in vscode or Reinstall Vscode if vscode files are currupted.